# Java return command

Tags: java, return, computer-science

So here I have this code that I have copied from my textbook. I do not fully understand how the factorial(k) gets its numbers from as only factorial(n) has a method calculating its value.

```
public void run(){
    int n = readInt("Enter the number of objects, n, in the set: ");
    int k = readInt("Enter numberto be chose,k, :");
    println("C("+ n + ", " + k + ") = " + combinations(n, k));
}
private int combinations(int n, int k){
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k));
}

private int factorial(int n){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        result*= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: What...? They call they same method, just with different inputs. I am confused by your confusion. EDIT: I think I see your confusion. the `n` being passed in in `combinations` is a *completely* different variable than the `n` being taken as a parameter to `factorial`. Please read up on scope!

Comment: Observe the difference between formal and actual parameters - The former is just a placeholder whose concrete lexicalisation plays no role at the calling site !

Comment: If you'd call factorial(3) where would the call go? Where does factorial(5) go? factorial(n)? Think about it.

Comment: @collapsar. Holy lexicalisation batman what did you just say?

Comment: @AndyBrown A formal parameter is what's passed in to the function -- `n` or `k` in this case are passed in to `factorial`. An actual parameter is in the method definition, `n` in `factorial`'s case, which is what they all end up as once you get inside `factorial`.

Comment: @AndyBrown Whether calling `factorial(n)` or `factorial(k)`, the argument is always mapped to the `n` in `private int factorial(int n)`. The phrasing might have been a bit overcomplicated ... ;-)

Comment: @tnw, my point is more that the OP is struggling with simple concepts. Most people with years of experience couldn't have unwound that sentence.

Comment: Haha fair point. @collapsar I think in your original comment you mean "latter", not "former".

Comment: @collapsar. I was really congratulating you on finding the most complicated way I have seen to explain the difference between an [*argument* and a *parameter*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). I won't forget your sentence in a long time. Anyway, you should just type out an answer. Comments like that are wasted effort.

Comment: @AndyBrown congrats accepted, thank you ;-). I was probably primed by the OP's reference to his textbook, expecting that he schould have run across the dichotomy before ... well, simplify your life ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the difference between *parameters* and *arguments*:

```
return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k));
```

Here the first `n` is an *argument* - a value passed to the function being called.

```
private int factorial(int n)
```

Here `n` is a *parameter* - a placeholder to use in defining what the function should do when being called with an argument. What use would it be to pass an argument if you had no way to express what the function should do with this argument ?

Comment: Perfect - your explanation matches with most of the [Java Tutorials about arguments and parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). FWIW I think the OP's other confusion is about scope - i.e. a variable declared in a method is not visible inside methods that the original method calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused by function calls and function definition.

The line `return factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k));` calls a function named `factorial` with different values (`n`, `n-k` and `k`).

Lines beginning by `private int factorial(int n){` define the function for any given value of `n`. `n` is a variable that denotes the value passed by a call.

If you call `combination` with value 10 and 4 (respectively), then it calls `factorial` with 10, 4 and 6 respectively. The first call binds 10 to n (the formal parameter of factorial), the second 4 to n (the formal parameter) and the third 6 to n (the formal parameter).

One definition, three use.